# Logstash stopping randomly after few hours

Tags: logstash

I'm getting a random error when I run logstash:

> 16:30:26.240 [[main]>worker0] ERROR logstash.pipeline - Exception in
>   pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please
>   check your filter configuration and restart Logstash.
>   {"exception"=>#,
>   "backtrace"=>["org/jruby/RubyString.java:3101:in `gsub'",
>   "org/jruby/RubyString.java:3069:in`gsub'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:317:in
>   `gsub_dynamic_fields'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:308:in`
>   gsub'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:290:in`
>   gsub'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:207:in
>   `filter'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:145:in`
>   do_filter'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:164:in
>   `multi_filter'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in`each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:161:in
>   `multi_filter'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filter_delegator.rb:41:in`
>   multi_filter'", "(eval):4135:in `initialize'",
>   "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in`each'", "(eval):4131:in
>   `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in`call'", "(eval):997:in
>   `filter_func'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:295:in`
>   filter_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:192:in`
>   each'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:191:in`
>   each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:294:in
>   `filter_batch'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:282:in`
>   worker_loop'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:258:in
>   `start_workers'"]} 16:30:26.542 [LogStash::Runner] FATAL
>   logstash.runner - An unexpected error occurred!
>   {:error=>#<InterruptedRegexpError: Regexp Interrupted>,
>   :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyString.java:3101:in`gsub'",
>   "org/jruby/RubyString.java:3069:in `gsub'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:317:in`
>   gsub_dynamic_fields'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:308:in
>   `gsub'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in`each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:290:in
>   `gsub'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:207:in`
>   filter'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:145:in
>   `do_filter'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:164:in`
>   multi_filter'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:161:in`
>   multi_filter'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filter_delegator.rb:41:in
>   `multi_filter'", "(eval):4135:in`initialize'",
>   "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "(eval):4131:in`
>   initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "(eval):997:in`
>   filter_func'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:295:in
>   `filter_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in`call'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:192:in
>   `each'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in`each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:191:in
>   `each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:294:in`
>   filter_batch'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:282:in
>   `worker_loop'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:258:in`
>   start_workers'"]}

My logstash config file is:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "SystemError"
        path => "/app/systemerr/**/*"
        start_position => "beginning"


        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\s"
            what => "previous"
        }      
    }

    file {
        type => "SystemOut"
        path => "/app/systemout/**/*"
            start_position => "beginning"


        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\["
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
    }

    file {
            type => "Errorlog"
        path => "/app/error/**/*"
            start_position => "beginning"


        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^FATAL"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
    }

    file {
            type => "Messagelog"
        path => "/app/message/**/*"
            start_position => "beginning"


        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^ERROR"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }      
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "SystemError" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "\[%{DATA:timestamp}] %{BASE16NUM:threadID} (?<shortname>\b[A-Za-z0-9\$]{2,}\b)%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }

        mutate {
            gsub => ["timestamp", " GMT\+05\:30", ""]
        }

        date {
            match => ["timestamp", "M/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:SSS"]
        }

        if ([message] =~ "^\tat") {
                drop {}
        }

        if ([path] =~ "113") {
            mutate {
                    add_field => { "server" => "113" }
            }
        } else {
            mutate {
                    add_field => { "server" => "117" }
            }
        }

    }

    if [type] == "SystemOut" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "\[%{DATA:timestamp}] %{BASE16NUM:threadID} (?<shortname>\b[A-Za-z0-9\$]{2,}\b)%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }

        mutate {
            gsub => ["timestamp", " GMT\+05\:30", ""]
        }

        date {
            match => ["timestamp", "M/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:SSS"]
        }

        if ([path] =~ "113") {
            mutate {
                    add_field => { "server" => "113" }
            }
        } else {
            mutate {
                    add_field => { "server" => "117" }
            }
        }       
    }

    if [type] == "Errorlog" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \| %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \| %{DATA:string} \: %{DATA:WebContainer} \| %{DATA:code} \| %{DATA:country} \| %{DATA:user} \| %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }

        date {
            match => ["timestamp", "yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
        }

        mutate { remove_field => [ "string" ] }

        if ([path] =~ "113") {
            mutate {
                    add_field => { "server" => "113" }
            }
        } else {
            mutate {
                    add_field => { "server" => "117" }
            }
        }       
    }

    if [type] == "Messagelog" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \| %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \| %{DATA:string} \: %{DATA:WebContainer} \| %{DATA:code} \| %{DATA:country} \| %{DATA:user} \| %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
            overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }

        date {
            match => ["timestamp", "yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
        }

        mutate { 
            remove_field => [ "string" ]
        }

        if ([path] =~ "113") {
            mutate {
                    add_field => { "server" => "113" }
            }
        } else {
            mutate {
                    add_field => { "server" => "117" }
            }
        }       

    }

}
```

Is there anything wrong in the config file? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

you are likely getting a `_grokparsefailure` and so the `timestamp` field isn't set.  You can surround the mutate/date with an `if` block like this:

```
if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
   mutate {
        gsub => ["timestamp", " GMT\+05\:30", ""]
   }

   date {
       match => ["timestamp", "M/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:SSS"]
   }
}
```

you may also want to add an `else { drop {} }`, but you should probably figure out what isn't matching first.

Comment: Yes, I do get _grokparsefailure but then the timestamp just defaults to the time the log was parsed...I dont understand why logstash should stop working altogether??

Comment: Logstash filters don't always handle errors properly. In this case it's trying to deterrence a field that's not there (hence the ruby stack dump). If you use my suggestion, it won't try to dereference a bad value and it won't die.